# Read PE files in C

Tags: portable-executable

I'm attempting to read a PE file in C. 
I have code `MZ` and then, I don't know to code `e_lfanew`.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <Windows.h>

  int main()
  {
        errno_t err;
        FILE *fp = NULL;
        char *buffer;
        err = fopen_s(&fp, "D:\\pe.exe", "rb");
        printf("----------dos header---------- \n");
        buffer = new char[3]; // malloc: cap phat bo nho//
        memset(buffer, 0x0, sizeof(char)* 3);      // memset: gan gia tri cho buffer//  
        fread(buffer, 2 * sizeof(char), 1, fp);
        printf("e_magic: %s \n", buffer);
   }
```

Also, I am aware this is possible via the `Win32 API`; however, I want to learn from this and do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Typically one would define a struct called DOS_Header and read the complete struct from the file. That struct then has a field `e_lfanew` which can directly be accessed without pointer arithmetics etc.

`e_lfanew` then points to the PE signature (`PE\0\0`), followed by the COFF header. Then the story repeats: create a struct called COFF_Header and read the complete struct from the file...

Answer (score 0):

As @thomas weller said you need to typecast your buffer to IMAGE_DOS_HEADER.

The last field tells you where the PE header is, then read that offset and typecast the buffer to IMAGE_NT_HEADER. The other way is to just map the file in and typecast the relevant buffers memory.

Answer (score 0):

To get details about any header information you can directly fill it to the structure for example

```
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER imgDosHdr = {0};
FILE *fp = fopen("Path_to_Pe","rb");
if(fp == NULL) return;
fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
fread(&imgDosHdr,1,sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER),fp);
fclose(fp);
```

Hence you can get all the details of PE file Header by Setting the
fseek.