# When reading a file in C Lang, what is the data type of the file you read using the "rb" property?

Tags: c, parsing, portable-executable

I am making a program to parse PE structure with C. I'm going to bring it in binary and parse it in length. Example) DOS header is 0x40(64) bytes long, so I tried to approach it from `binary_buf[0]` to `binary_buf[39]`.
What data type should I read the file?

I don't know what to write because it's all the same whether I use an int or a char. And I would appreciate it if you could tell me why I should use that data type.

```
unsigned char *binary_buf = NULL; 

fp = fopen(filename, "rb"); 
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("이 파일은 열 수 없습니다.\n");
    return 0;
}

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

binary_buf = malloc(size+1);
fread(binary_buf, 1, size, fp);
fclose(fp);

printf("%d", binary_buf[0]); //77 = 0x4D == 'M'
```

Thank you for reading my question. Have a good day!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182852/read-pe-files-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading a binary file, an `unsigned char` array seems exactly what you need.

Note that allocating one extra byte does not seem necessary for this job as you are not creating a C string from the file contents.

Reading the contents of the PE head as single bytes is the best portable approach: The header data has a specific layout that might not be correctly matched by a C structure because of alignment and endianness issues.

After checking the signature, you should extract the relevant values from the known offsets in the header and construct the file offsets using appropriate integer arithmetics.

The DOS Header is 64 bytes long and has the following layout:

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER {      // DOS .EXE header
    WORD   e_magic;                     // Magic number
    WORD   e_cblp;                      // Bytes on last page of file
    WORD   e_cp;                        // Pages in file
    WORD   e_crlc;                      // Relocations
    WORD   e_cparhdr;                   // Size of header in paragraphs
    WORD   e_minalloc;                  // Minimum extra paragraphs needed
    WORD   e_maxalloc;                  // Maximum extra paragraphs needed
    WORD   e_ss;                        // Initial (relative) SS value
    WORD   e_sp;                        // Initial SP value
    WORD   e_csum;                      // Checksum
    WORD   e_ip;                        // Initial IP value
    WORD   e_cs;                        // Initial (relative) CS value
    WORD   e_lfarlc;                    // File address of relocation table
    WORD   e_ovno;                      // Overlay number
    WORD   e_res[4];                    // Reserved words
    WORD   e_oemid;                     // OEM identifier (for e_oeminfo)
    WORD   e_oeminfo;                   // OEM information; e_oemid specific
    WORD   e_res2[10];                  // Reserved words
    LONG   e_lfanew;                    // File address of new exe header
} IMAGE_DOS_HEADER, *PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER;
```

Where `WORD` is a 16-bit little endian integer and `LONG` a 32-bit little endian integer.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int read_PE_file(const char *filename) {
    unsigned char *binary_buf = NULL; 
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb"); 
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s\n", filename);
        return -1;
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long length = ftell(fp);
    unsigned long size;
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    if (length < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error seeking file %s\n", filename);
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }
    size = length;
    if (size < 64) {
        fprintf(stderr, "file %s too short, size=%lu\n", filename, size);
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }
#if LONG_MAX > SIZE_MAX
    if (size > SIZE_MAX) {
        fprintf(stderr, "file %s too large, size=%lu\n", filename, size);
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }
#endif
    if ((binary_buf = malloc(size)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating %lu byte buffer for file %s\n", size, filename);
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }
    if (fread(binary_buf, 1, size, fp) != size) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file %s\n", filename);
        free(binary_buf);
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    if (binary_buf[0] != 0x4D || binary_buf[1] != 0x5A) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File %s does not have MZ signature\n", filename);
        free(binary_buf);
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }
    unsigned long offset = binary_buf[60] +
                           (binary_buf[61] << 8) + 
                           ((unsigned long)binary_buf[62] << 16) + 
                           ((unsigned long)binary_buf[63] << 24);
      
    if (offset > size) {
        fprintf(stderr, "new executable offset %lu greater than file size %lu for file %s\n", offset, size, filename);
        free(binary_buf);
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("new executable offset: %lu\n", offset);
    [...]
    free(binary_buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know that the difference between unsigned char and just char is an integer expression range. But the reason for using unsigned char is to consider the situation when the size of hexadecimal is converted to decimal?

Comment: @Wonlf: the type `char` can be signed by default on common architectures, which may produce unexpected behavior when used in computations. It is recommended to only use `char` for actual C strings and textual data and use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` for binary data.